# JSON Serializer is giving an issue, when the Json string contains string and array of strings

Tags: json, string, serialization, arraylist

When a Json string contains 'key1:value1', this can be converted to the Dictionary type.

But in my case, it also contains an array of strings along with the above key:value, ie:

```
{k1:v1; "key2\":[{\"Key11\":{\"key21\":\"Val21\",\"key22\":\"val22\"}]
```

(The Json data contains some strings and some arrays.)

When I use Dictionary<string, string[]> or Dictionary<string, ArrayList> -- it is failing at the value as string - cannot convert string to string[], etc.

Still Dictionary<string, object> can be used, but is there any better way to handle this?

thanks
Phani

Comment: Is it a fixed structure as you've written, or are you looking for a general solution?

Comment: General Solution, assuming that we dont know the structures...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the structure at compile-time, then there's no other way to serialize a JSON string-- it has to be Dictionary<string,object>.  However, if you're using C# 4.0, you can use **DynamicObject**.  Since dynamic typing defers type resolution until runtime, if you serialize using this approach, you can treat your serialized object as strongly-typed (albeit without compile-time support).  That means you can use JSON-style dot notation to access properties:

```
MyDynamicJsonObject.key2
```

To accomplish this, you can inherit from DynamicObject, and implement the **TryGetMember** method ([quoted from this link, which has a full implementation)](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx):

```
public class DynamicJsonObject : DynamicObject
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public DynamicJsonObject(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
    {
        this.Dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = this.Dictionary[binder.Name];

        if (result is IDictionary<string, object>)
        {
            result = new DynamicJsonObject(result as IDictionary<string, object>);
        }
        else if (result is ArrayList && (result as ArrayList) is IDictionary<string, object>)
        {
            result = new List<DynamicJsonObject>((result as ArrayList).ToArray().Select(x => new DynamicJsonObject(x as IDictionary<string, object>)));
        }
        else if (result is ArrayList)
        {
            result = new List<object>((result as ArrayList).ToArray());
        }

        return this.Dictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name);
    }
}
```

Note that dynamic typing currently doesn't support indexer notation, so for arrays, you'll need to [implement a workaround using notation like this](http://www.nikhilk.net/CSharp-Dynamic-Programming-JSON.aspx):

```
MyDynamicJsonObject.key2.Item(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not valid JSON, e.g. every key and value should be surrounded by `"`, e.g. `{"k1":"v1"}`, the number of opening and closing curly brackets must match, if you escape the `"` character by using `\"` you must add a another `"` character, e.g. `"key2\""`

Use a tool such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate that your JSON is correct.